# What does this new icon mean?

Tags: overwatch

I'm wondering what this new icon means. The number, border and colors change size and shape between players.

[image]

Answer (score 20, accepted):

That icon shows a player's Endorsement level, while the colours represent how many endorsements of each kind that player has received:

- Sportsmanship in green
- Good Teammate in purple
- Shot Caller in orange

You can endorse other players at any time after a quick play or competitive match has ended but before ending the next match that allows endorsements.

Some arcade game modes also support endorsements, in both competitive and non-competitive versions:

- 3v3 Group Elimination
- Capture the Flag
- Lúcio Ball
- Team Deathmatch

For more information, visit [the official website's page on endorsements](https://playoverwatch.com/en-us/game/endorsements/).

Comment: Endorsements are supported in the arcade games. I only play arcade and got some endorsments. However, free for all is not supported.

Comment: @Ckankonmange Endorsements are not supported in the arcade, no.

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer My own experience and the last comment of this [post](https://www.polygon.com/2018/7/2/17527694/overwatch-endorsements-how-to-level-up-explainer) tells me you can.

Comment: @Ckankonmange Partially correct, as it turns out.